# React Testing Error: TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /01:20/i. Error in CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying writing a test case. The application is similar to a Graph where there is some delay in loading/refreshing data. I am trying to search "01:20" text value in the graph.
While running in local dev. server, the test case is passing. But in the pipeline its failing and showing the following error.

```
test('renders example', async () => {
   await waitFor(() => {
        expect(screen.getByText(/01:20/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
   })
   
   // const endPoint = await screen.findAllByText(/01:20/i)
   // expect(endPoint[0]).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```

TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /01:20/i. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

I have tried using `waitFor`, `findBy`, `getBy` queries but all are failing. As in local, I am running `npm test`, all the test cases are passing. I am using react-testing-library with jest.

As I am new to react testing, any solution/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you ruled out that it is just taking longer in the pipeline? Try extending the wait time  `await waitFor(() => expect... , { timeout: 10000 });` or `expect(await screen.findByText(/01:20/i, {}, { timeout: 10000 }).toBeInTheDocument();`

Comment: I have used like this as Jest default timeout is 5000 ms and I am getting an error.
`await screen.findByText(/23:30/i, {}, { timeout: 4000 })`
Still I am getting the same error in this line, with the above error I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I suggested a 10 second timeout to rule out delays in the pipeline. If you have tried this then can you provide the component you are testing?